# python 3 class inheritance issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        self.a = 2
        self.b = 3


class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 4
        self.c = 5

class D(C, B):
    def __init__(self):
        C.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        self.d = 6

obj = D()
print(obj.a)
```

My understanding is that python will first search class C then B then A to get a. So print(obj.a) will print out 4 when searching class C. But the answer is 2. This means that Python got self.a = 2 from class B instead of self.a = 4 from class C. Can anyone explain the reasons? Thank you

Comment: You *explicitly* call `B.__init__` after `C.__init__`. You should be using `super` to manage the multiple inheritance, and read up on the MRO (method resolution order) to see the order superclasse method implementations will be called in.

Comment: You manually called the parent `__init__` methods; since `B.__init__()` is called last, `self.a = 2` is executed last (after `A.__init__()` was called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no search going on here. You are making explicit, direct calls to unbound methods, passing in `self` manually. These are *simple function calls*, nothing more.

So this is just a question of tracing the execution order:

```
D() -> D.__init__(self)
    C.__init__(self)
        self.a = 4
    B.__init__(self)
        A.__init__(self)
            self.a = 1
        self.a = 2
```

So `a` is assigned `4`, then `1`, then `2`.